# What is Error in value[[3L]](cond) in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have a code that has an error because of not enough memory. Actually I do a linear model (lm) on a big data. The problem is not because it gives me the error, that I want to log, but because it contains `value[[3L]](cond)`.

My error looks like this:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond): While training model Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.4 Gb
```

The code that logs it look like this (using logging lib):

```
tryCatch({
  # some code
  tryCatch({
    # some other code
  }, warning = function(war){
    logwarn(war, logger = "MyLogger")
  }, error = function(err){
    stop(paste("While training model", err, sep = " "))
  })
  some more code
}, error = function(err){
  logerror(err, logger = "MyLogger")
})
```

My problem is why is it saying `Error in value[[3L]](cond):`? Is it something wrong that I did and I do not know? Shouldn't it be just `Error: <error message>`?

Comment: What? Why -1? I am new to R, so if I do a bad practice, tell me. Or if it always show that in front of any error, then tell me, I have not found big deal on google about it (except that it has appeared in a problem of going next iteration if an error/warning appears)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are issuing `stop()` in your inner `tryCatch`, and internally, when an error condition is raised, `tryCatch()` calls the error handler you provided which is the third element in a list (internal to `tryCatch`).  It calls that that handler passing condition `cond` via: `value[[3L]](cond)`.  Since your error handler calls stop, that's where the most recent error was called.

You can use `traceback()` (which implicitly calls `print()`) to view the call stack in the error handler like so:

```
tryCatch({
    stop('')
},error=function(err){
    traceback()
})
```

which yields:

```
5: print(where) at #4
4: value[[3L]](cond)
3: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
2: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
1: tryCatch({
       stop()
   }, error = function(err) {
       print(where)
   })
```

If you want to retain the call-stack from the original error but have a more informative error message, just edit the error and re-raise it :

```
  tryCatch({
    # some other code
  }, warning = function(war){
    logwarn(war, logger = "MyLogger")
  }, error = function(err){
    # edit the error message
    err$message <- paste("While training model", err, sep = " ")
    # and re-raise
    stop(err)
  })
```